# How to update entity in entity-framework manually

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a project used entity framework, and now I want to add a new entity to the framework, the database have some slight changes which don't influence the code, however, if I want to add a new entity by update wizard the changes will be implemented too and errors will be thrown. I think the only way is to add entity manually, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can delete the entity and choose update model from database, and choose the updated table. Then it will create a new entity with all the fields present.

Comment: It is the final solution, but I think I'd better not do it, the entire project is so big and I don't want to change too much code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use partial classes for your own code when using Entity Framework with a Model. In the partial classes you put in your code (so when you update the Model you won't loose it). I would recommend that you update your model and fix the errors, because you will have to update it more often in the future and you don't want to write the xml manually on every change.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will do like this if I start a new project, but it is not the solution for now, anyway thanks.

Comment: He could map the entity to a proxy class, which contains the neccessary properties ( could be all ) and methods for manipulating the data. This way you wont expose your entity to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to create a new entity representing a table in the database, you can use [this procedure from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174712/336648). That should provide you with a new entity class generated from only one of the tables while ignoring the rest of the DB.

**Update, in answer to a question below:**

If you are able to create the entity class, but it does not show up where you need it, make sure you've added it in your `Context` (there should be a class which inerits `DbContext`). Look for something like:

```
public DbSet<SomeExistingEntityClass> SomeExistingEntityClass1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<SomeExistingEntityClass> SomeExistingEntityClass2 { get; set; }
...
public DbSet<YourEntityClass> YourEntityClass { get; set; } // <-- Add this
```

You might also need to add a **configuration** for your new entity. There are several ways to do this; in my case, configs are specified like this in the `context` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeExistingEntityClass1Config());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeExistingEntityClass2Config());
    ....
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityClassConfig()); // <-- Add this
}
```

..and then the config class itself looks like:

```
public class MyEntityClassConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntityClassConfig>
{
    public MyEntityClassConfig()
    {
        ToTable("My_Database_Table_Name");
        HasKey(table => table.Name_of_primary_key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed it, the model is successfully added but the link to table is missing.

Comment: @sayume How do you mean the link to the table is missing - are you not able to find and create the entity class from the DB? I've updated my answer a little. Don't know if this will be the same in your situation, but I hope it might help you.